# Under EASA regulations, what constitutes loggable flight time?

Tags: easa-regulations, logging, time, sweden

It wasn't too hard to find questions and answers here discussing [flight time](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/30935/753) as defined [by the US FAA](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11844/753).

However, I'm curious about EASA regulations, and if applicable specifically as implemented in Sweden.

Based on the relevant EASA regulations, **at what point do I note the start and end time of a flight for the purposes of flight time logging?**

I looked through the copy of the regulations that I have, but couldn't find anything relating to logging (of flight time or otherwise).

Citations, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [FCL.050(g)](http://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/acceptable-means-of-compliance-and-guidance-materials/part-fcl-amc-gm):

> Flight time is recorded: (1) for aeroplanes, touring motor gliders and
>   powered-lift aircraft, from the  moment an aircraft first moves to
>   taking off until the moment it finally  comes to rest at the end of
>   the flight;

That seems to be the same as the FAA regulation.